# Cypress: How to check client side validation via JavaScript?

Tags: validation, cypress, server-side-rendering

I have a field `name` where the value `1` is not allowed. Per JavaScript I insert the text 'This value is not valid' in `form`-element when the cursor left the `name`-field.
I would like to test this.
I have tried this code:

```
cy.get('#name').clear().type('1')
cy.get('#street').trigger('click')
cy.get('#street').focus().then(() => {
  cy.get('#form').should('contain.text', 'This value is not valid')
})
```

Sometimes the test works, sometimes not. In the application itself, the validation works without any problems.

What do I need to do to make sure the code tests valid?

Comment: What error message do you receive? Where does the test fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to use the `.blur()` command, from the way you describe the user process.

You would think that `.focus()` to another element would also do it, but maybe the validation is tied into the specific blur event type.

This is how it would look

```js
cy.get('#name').clear().type('1').blur()
cy.get('#form').should('contain.text', 'This value is not valid')
```

Note there's no need for a `.then()` wrapper as the commands will process sequentially.

Also try a simple `{enter}`

```js
cy.get('#name').clear().type('1{enter}')
cy.get('#form').should('contain.text', 'This value is not valid')
```

Ideally, you want to investigate the source code of the app to see what event or events are involved in the validation process.

It may even be a custom event, for example a `validate` event that requires the Cypress test to trigger that event.

```js
cy.get('#name').clear().type('1').trigger('validate')
cy.get('#form').should('contain.text', 'This value is not valid')
```